# Image in XAML from another assembly is not loaded (does not appear)

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, .net-assembly

I don't understand, an image from the same assembly is shown as expected.
An image from another assembly (referenced) seems to not be loaded (does not appear).

Partial code:

```
        <Button Command="Play" ToolTip="Execute Macro">
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/ParametricStudySharedGui;component/Image/arrowRight32x32.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
        </Button>
```

I did try to add next line in App.OnStartup without success:

```
    Assembly.Load("ParametricStudySharedGui");
```

That happen in my application MainWindow on an image defined as "Resource" (like the one from the same assembly which work fine).

Please also take note that the image is shown as expected in Visual Studio design window.

I also tried to modified resource path without success as:

```
<Image Source="/ParametricStudySharedGui;component/Image/arrowRight32x32.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
```

Any idea ???

Comment: This is just a guess, but try removing the space from the file name (and the corresponding URI).  I don't know for sure whether spaces are allowed in resource names.

Comment: @Mike Strobel, I tried and I have same result. The icon is there in design mode. I will add that information in question.

Comment: And the image is in an "Image" folder directly under the "ParametricStudySharedGui" project?

Comment: @Mike Strobel, yes. I suppose it should be well defined because it is shown in design window and also either Visual Studio or Resharper does not complain. I restarted VS just in case (I know it is silly) but it did not solve my problem too.

Comment: On occasion, I find that Visual Studio (infuriatingly) does not properly detect new WPF resources that have been added to a project.  Try doing a full Clean and then Rebuild on your solution and see if the image suddenly shows up.

Comment: @Mike Stobel, GOTCHA !!! Thanks so much ! Put it as an answer please...

Comment: Done.  I can't tell you how much time I've wasted over that little bug.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please also take note that the image is shown as expected in Visual Studio design window.

In that case, I suspect Visual Studio simply didn't rebuild the assembly containing the image.  I find this happens from time to time: if you add or overwrite an image or other resource, but you make no code changes, the new/updated image may not get included in the build.

Try doing a full Clean and Rebuild of your solution.